# Not receiving the updated data from firebase in the flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to do live-tracking in flutter app for which I'm using the flutter realtime database. To test the code I'm changing the data directly in the firebase and checking if it was printed in the console. I need to update the marker as per the location updates from the firebase. However, I'm not being able to figure out why the data is not being listened to by my app.

Here's my code.

```
class _TrackMapState extends State<TrackMap> {
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  List<Marker> _allMarkers = [];

  final firebaseDB = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _allMarkers.add(Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId("Destination"),
        draggable: false,
        position: LatLng(widget.model.requests[widget.index]["latitude"],
            widget.model.requests[widget.index]["longitude"])));

    firebaseDB
        .child(widget.model.requests[widget.index]["assignedAgent"])
        .once()
        .then((DataSnapshot data) {
      setState(() {
        _allMarkers.add(Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId("agent"),
            draggable: false,
            position: LatLng(data.value["latitude"], data.value["longitude"])));
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _key,
      appBar: CustomAppBar("Requests"),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.grey[300])),
        child: GoogleMap(
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(widget.model.requests[widget.index]["latitude"],
                widget.model.requests[widget.index]["longitude"]),
            zoom: 9,
          ),
          markers: Set.from(_allMarkers),
        ),
      ),
      drawer: SideDrawer(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _trackCollectionAgent,
        child: Icon(Icons.location_searching),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _trackCollectionAgent() async {
    firebaseDB
        .child(widget.model.requests[widget.index]["assignedAgent"])
        .onChildChanged
        .listen((event) {
      var key = event.snapshot.key;
      var value = event.snapshot.value;

      // not sure what data I'm going to get here and 
      //so trying to print it here
      print(key);
      print(value);

      Marker _marker = Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId("agent"),
          draggable: false,
          position: (key == "latitude")
              ? LatLng(value, _allMarkers[1].position.longitude)
              : LatLng(_allMarkers[1].position.latitude, value));
      setState(() {
        _allMarkers[1] = _marker;
        print(_allMarkers);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the workaround which I used.

```
void initState() {
    ....

    setUpTimedFetch();
  }

  setUpTimedFetch() {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 5000), (timer) {
        _future = Future.value(timer.tick.toString());
        firebaseDB
            .child(widget.data["assignedAgent"])
            .once()
            .then((DataSnapshot data) {
          print(data.value);
          Marker _marker = Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId("agent"),
            draggable: false,
            icon:
                BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueBlue),
            infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                title: "Agent",
                snippet:
                    "(${data.value['latitude']}, ${data.value['longitude']})"),
            position: LatLng(data.value["latitude"], data.value["longitude"]),
          );
          setState(() {
            _allMarkers[1] = _marker;
            print(_allMarkers);
          });
        });
    });
  }
```